# L'histoire des hommes, dont chacune est unique et qui toutes se ressemblent

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

Bonjour,

*Roses de sang Roses d'Ouessant* de Janine Boissard :

> Juin est là et sa douceur. La mer bruisse comme un feuillet d'argent
> sur lequel s'inscrirait l'histoire des hommes, dont chacune est unique
> et **qui** toutes se ressemblent.

Quel est le rôle de "qui" ? Est-ce qu'il remplace "chacune" et "histoire" ?

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il y a un implicite « toutes les histoires » là qui permet de parler de « chacune » d'entre elles et qui fait que « toutes » et « se ressemblent » sont bien accordés.

Quand on parle d'une chose que possède chaque membre d'un groupe, c'est-à-dire une chose dont chaque membre en a une, on emploie le singulier ; cf. la phrase qui m'a appris cette règle, tirée de *La peste* de Camus :

> En entrant, Cottard  et  Rambert  essuyèrent  leur  front.

Cette manière de distribuer des fronts diffère de celle de l'anglais :

> As they entered, Cottard and Rambert wiped their forehead**s**.

Dans le cas de « front » il est facile de déterminer la signification voulue, étant que l'idée d'un seul front partagé entre plusieurs hommes est risible. Mais cet emploi d' « histoire » est plus ambigu, puisqu'on pourrait parler soit de l'histoire de tous les hommes, c.-à.-d. celle de la race, soit de l'histoire qui appartient à chaque homme. Dans cet exemple, « chacune » et « toutes » nous mènent à la deuxième interprétation.

(Même si le sens de la phrase elle-même — que chacune est unique et que pourtant toutes se ressemblent — joue peut-être sur cette ambiguïté !)

Comment: Merci. En russe, ce serait _As they entered, Cottard and Rambert wiped **his** forehead._ :)

Comment: @Oreste Ha :) I tried to read the Google Translate result in Russian to see if I could make the comparison, but quickly got in over my head and settled for English...